# Efficiently populating column with results

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate column AO (from AO2 to lastrow) with the variable "ReportedPipeline", which is calculated based on values in columns of the same row (columns O, P, T, U, W).

Whilst I have been able to calculate "ReportedPipeline", I am struggling to efficiently fill down the values to the last row.

I have created a loop which populates a value in AO2, then moves the activecell down by 1 row, though this is very inefficient. I have seen the "How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA" articles though can't figure out how I can apply this.

The variables I've used:

```
Dim oppstart As Date            'actual opportunity start
Dim oppend As Date              'actual opportunity end
Dim confidence As Integer       'opportunity confidence
Dim outstanding As Single       'outstanding amount
Dim status As String            'opportunity status - Lost or Open
Dim thisyear As Integer         'value of this year
Dim nextyear As Integer         'value of next year
Dim ReportedPipeline As Single  '(Outstanding amount / The subs' length in months)* months of this sub in this year
Dim monthsdiff As Integer       'How long the full length of the subscription is in months
Dim monthslength As Integer     'Length in months of subscription this year

status = Range("w" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
oppstart = Range("t" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
oppend = Range("u" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
confidence = Range("p" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
outstanding = Range("o" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
```

If it helps I can share the full code.

Thanks!

Comment: Goodness, there must be squillions of results in Google for finding the last row in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not having any problems with code for finding the last row, though am looking to understand how I can more efficiently populate column AO with a variable "ReportedPipeline" which is calculated based on values of the variables in the same row. Currently this is done by running a loop, offsetting the selected cell by 1 row, though this is inefficient.

Comment: I see. Why can't you use a formula?

Comment: You only showed the part of the code that has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off looping through the rows, something like:

```
i = 2 to Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    status = Range("w" & i).Value
    oppstart = Range("t" & i).Value
    oppend = Range("u" & i).Value
    confidence = Range("p" & i).Value
    outstanding = Range("o" & i).Value 

    'Do you calculation here

    Range("AO" & i).Value = Foo 'Foo is the result of you calculation

Next i
```

to speed things up you can also use:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

At the beginning of your sub

That said, if the calculation could be done with formulas it might be better to have formulas in column `AO`

Comment: You don't have to set `Application.ScreenUpdating` back to "true", it automatically goes back to true when you exit the sub

Comment: It *should* automatically go back to true, but there's quite a few documented cases where it strangely has not, and in the past I've experienced this personally. So I always set it back to TRUE just in case. Maybe the issue is long solved, but I prefer to be sure than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping through a range - which imposes overhead for each iteration of the loop as data is transferred between Excel and VBA - it is far more efficient to either simply use VBA to populate a formula in a column in Excel (which takes one transfer) or to bring the data into VBA in one go using a Variant Array, iterate the array in VBA, then send it back to Excel in one go.